# Связать react js и php. Возможно?

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs

Начал изучать react js,  node js. Такая мысль пришла. Если для, условно говоря, создания сайта, SPA нужны некоторые элементы, и потом просто клиент шлёт аякс к серверу а сервер (выступает в роли API) и отдаёт клиенту json который потом уже обрабатывается java script-ом.

API ведь вполне можно реализовать на php? То есть php скрипт будет коннектится например с mysql, получать необходимые данные, формировать json.

Но получается что ещё в клиенте нужно сохранять какие-то значения? Например ID который уйдёт аяксом в php и по нему произойдёт выборка...

Где на клиенте (и на клиенте ли?) хранить этот ID? Как?

Дело в том что JS знаю только примерно на 4 из 10..., а вот с php работаю давно и много, но уже одного html, css, php и mysql становиться маловато.

И вроде бы после изучения некоторой информации по реакту кажется что не так все и сложно, и мысли как-то расплылись, не могу их собрать воедино, но кажется что очень очень близко к пониманию.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен. ReactJS - это фронт-энд, PHP - бэк-энд. ReactJS можно привязать к ЛЮБОМУ типу бэк-энда даже если в качестве него будет выступать Java, Python, Ryby и т.д.

На счёт где хранить id: тут выбор большой, начиная от куки и заканчивая localStorage и sessionStorage.

Есть так же CacheStorage и IndexedDb. Как Вы поняли из названия, все они используются для разных целей.

Comment: Могу добавить, что когда мы говорим про `SPA`, мы должны в голове держать и `SSR` для сео и прочих поисковых плюшек, вот тут у `php` действительно есть просядки, если сравнивать с той-же нодой (еще держим в уме то что react.js и прочие изначально писались под ноду). т.к. у ноды фронт и бек написаны на одном языке там все легко настраивается и не геморно. а вот у `php` тут глобальные проблемки... есть костыль в виде `V8js` для `SSR`, но нужно уметь хорошо им пользоваться ¯|_(ツ)_/¯